# Javascript Recursion returning undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm struggling in a recursive Javascript function to find a specific subdirectory. This is my code:

```
function navigateToParent() {
    var parentFullPath = parentDirectory(); // gets the full Path String
    if (parentFullPath != null) {
        var parent = getDirectoryByName(parentFullPath, rootDirectory);
        // set the parent directory object as the current one
        currentDirectory(parent);
    }
}

function getDirectoryByName(fullName, myDirectory) {
    if (myDirectory.fullName == fullName) {
        return myDirectory;
    } else {
        var subs = myDirectory.subDirectories;
        for (i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) {
            return getDirectoryByName(fullName,subs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Every directory object has the properties `fullName`(string),`subDirectories`(array of directories) and `files`(array of files). My aim is to get the correct directory object, where it's fullName is matching.

I know, that i have to break the for loop in some way, but i don't know how to do it exactly.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the directory object?

Comment: Inside your for loop, you'd really only want to `return` if `getDirectoryByName` returned a result, otherwise you'll never check the rest of the children

Comment: `getDirectoryByName` - not all execution paths return a value, and `for` with `return` is simply wrong logic since it won't check anything other than the first subdirectory.

Comment: @Daniel You should put your *EDIT* in as an answer and mark it as the solution. It will help future readers easily identify the solution

Comment: @ RGraham done ;) but i can't mark is as answer yet

Answer (score 0):

After overthinking the logic i came to this solution (seems to work):

```
function getDirectoryByName(fullName, myDirectory) {
    if (myDirectory.fullName == fullName) {
        return myDirectory;
    } else {
        var subs = myDirectory.subDirectories;
        for (i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) {
            var match = getDirectoryByName(fullName, subs[i]);
            if (typeof match !== "undefined"){
                return match;
            }
        }
    }
}
```